# Unifying a term with the Nth value of a list

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble implementing a Prolog predicate, `vector_reference(L,N,V)`, so that when given a list "L" and an index "N" it will unify V with the Nth value of the list.

The example print outs are below:

```
?- vector_reference([2,3,4], 3, V).
V = 4

?- vector_reference([2, [2,3],’hello’]),2,V).
V = [2,3]
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard library, `library(lists)` (autoloaded, you don't need to do anything) there are two predicates: `nth0/3` and `nth1/3` that do exactly what you need. For example:

```
?- nth1(2, [2,[2,3],hello], V).
V = [2, 3].
```

Btw, the SWI-Prolog webpage has a very useful search function. Typing `nth` in there would have given you the answer.

Comment: See my teacher never mentioned this stuff just threw us in the lion's den. This worked amazingly cause I just did vector_reference(L,N,V) :- nth1(N,L,V). after writing so many lines to get nothing...